# How do I get identical kernel release and kernel versions across multiple systems?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

How do I get identical kernel versions across multiple machines?

I have 8 machines which I want to be on identical OS versions.  They originally started out as Ubuntu 14.04 installs (at differing times) and they've been patched regularly via `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`.  When I execute `uname -a` on these systems, I get several different versions of the kernel release and kernel versions.

```
$> cexec uname -a 

************************* host-all *************************
--------- alpha-front---------
Linux alpha-front 3.13.0-132-generic #181-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 13:25:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- alpha-back---------
Linux alpha-back 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- qa-front---------
Linux qa-front 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- qa-back---------
Linux qa-back 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- staging-front---------
Linux staging-front 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- staging-back---------
Linux staging-back 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- prod-front---------
Linux prod-front 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------- prod-back---------
Linux prod-back 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The all appear to be on the same version of the OS

```
$> cexec cat /etc/lsb-release

************************* host-all *************************
--------- alpha-front---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- alpha-back---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- qa-front---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- qa-back---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- staging-front---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- staging-back---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- prod-front---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
--------- prod-back---------
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

So, kernel release `3.19.0-80-generic` with kernel version `#88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017` seems to be the most recent.  This is what I'd like to ensure all systems are running.

I've duplicated the `/etc/apt/sources.list` from my staging-back server to my alpha-front server and did the `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` cycle and yet I still have kernel release `3.13.0-132-generic` with kernel version `#181-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 13:25:03 UTC 2017` (no apparent changes).

There are slight differences in the virtual hardware between systems (128MB RAM vs 64MB RAM, 16 cores vs 8 cores, 500GB root disk vs 2.3TB root disk).

What do I need to do to get identical kernel releases and kernel versions?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you need to reboot to start a new kernel, so on each machine `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update && sudo reboot` . Update just the kernel if you do not wish to update the whole system.

Comment: I did the update cycle (apt-get udpate; apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade; reboot) after ensuring sources.list  are identical and I still get the same results.  Kernel release and version are still at 3.13.0-132-generic #181-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 13:25:03 UTC 2017.

Comment: You can use either the initial kernel, or the HWE kernel on all machines. The initial is 3.13, the latest HWE is 4.4.

Comment: @Pilot6 - can you add details either as a comment or to my answer. I am concerned HWE is not obvious to all users.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with point releases

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support#Ubuntu_Kernel_Support

To update all your boxes to kernel 4.4 run

DESKTOP :

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

MULTIARCH DESKTOP

If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64, for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved command, like this:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
```

SERVER

Install the HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (xenial):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial 

sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr

Comment: Ugh... this is not at all intuitive.

The graphic for 14.04.x Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule shows that Ubuntu 14.04.5 (v4.4) and this is Xenial 16.04 HWE Kernel.

So, if I understand this correctly,  even though I'm upgrading a 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) machine to version 14.04.5, I'm going to specify a Xenial package (where Xenial Xerus is normally associated with Ubuntu 16.04).  Yet I'm going to actually end up with a 14.04.5 Ubuntu version at the end of the upgrade process.

Comment: Interesting. I used your server HWE kernel update command on a machine on which I'd upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.3 and I have a 4.4 HWE kernel while the DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION remained at "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS".   This suggests that distribution release versions are independent of the kernel versions, which I wasn't aware you could do.

So, if I want all my machines at kernel v3.19, I should use 
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid 

sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid.  Is this correct?